# Convert spark dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe with two columns; Stars (numeric value), and categories (string of tags, eg.: "Restaurant, Italien, High-end"). I wish to recreate the dataframe so that categories is instead a count of tags. in the above example categories would instead become 3.

I've tried treating the dataframe as a pandas dataframe, but it does not seem to work. I am new to Spark so perhaps it is because i don't really grasp the idea of RDD's.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the code for better understanding of problem. Based on the description of your problem, you can try something like this:

```
df['CategoryCount'] = df['categories'].str.split(',').str.len()
```

df is your original dataframe and CategoryCount is new column which contains the count of tags. You can drop your categories column also if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but that would be for python dataframes. This however is spark dataframes.

Meanwhile i did find the following solution to work:


`%spark2.pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, size
business=df.select("stars", size(split(df.categories, ", ")).alias("numcat"))`